Android: Test unit is being run twice
Been trying to consolidate unit test report for a multi-module Android project with custom Gradle task using TestReport.
project level build.gradle
tasks.register<TestReport>("testReport") {
    description = "Custom Gradle task for consolidating test report"
    group = "Custom Tasks"

    destinationDirectory.set(file("$rootDir/reports/tests/unitTest"))
    // Combine all 'test' task results into a single HTML report
    testResults.from(subprojects.map {
        it.tasks.withType(Test::class)
    })
}

It works but each test code seems being executed twice. My guess is because debug and release variant both runs. Is there a way to only execute this task with specified build variant.


